# Is there an equivalent for setInterval() that works on opera mini?

Tags: javascript, opera-mini

I already Tried using a while loop, under the thought that it looped every milisecond or every half or whatever, but it loops whenever possible...

Answer (score 0):

setInterval and setTimeout don't work in Opera Mini? Didn't know that.

If setTimeout works, you can create a function that calls itself back over and over.

```
var myfunc = function(){
   //do something

   setTimeout(function(){ myfunc(); }, 100);
}();
```

Loops execute instantly in a human's perception of time, so a hundred loops and five loops essentially finish in the same speed -- provided your processor isn't a classic historical potato

Comment: I'll Try that. I think that if the devs of opera mini didn't add setInerval, they wouldn't add setTImeout, as they are similar commands in structure and in purpose...